# HTML Parser for pulling Text Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi does anyone know of an HTML parser in Javascript?  I need it to basically pull all the readable text out of the file for my tag cloud...not metatags only but everything within:

tags:

```
<meta><p><h1-3><textbox><textarea>
```

basically you get the idea.

I saw John Resig's but that changes everything to XML.  Before I try and use that and then just parse the XML, which may be easier I don't know, I wanted to see if there was something out there already.

Any help would be appreciate, until then I'll just keep looking around or I might just make it myself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(myfileContents).text();
```

Where `myFileContents` is a string containing the HTML in your file.

Comment: Well, jQuery isn't available in PHP (it is, after all, a Javascript library) so yeah, PHP would be a different beast. :)

Comment: @Verber: You're going to have to be more specific than that.